# Wie sagt man „to track (an asset)“ auf Deutsch? How would you say “to track (an asset)” in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb, single-word-request

Es ist für die Beschreibung einer Asset-Tracking-Software. Das Beste, was ich bis jetzt gefunden habe, ist *verfolgen*, aber ich finde es nicht ideal. Um etwas mehr Kontext zu geben, es geht um Labor-Assets (Geräte), die manchmal von Raum zu Raum verschoben werden.

It is for the description of an asset tracking software. The best I have found so far is *verfolgen* but I do not think it expresses it in the same way. To give some more context, it is for laboratory assets (equipment), which is moved from room to room sometimes.

Comment: Welcome to the german language SE. Just for clarification: it's about knowing where the asset is or at least where it has been seen recently, right? As in tracking parcels?

Comment: Yes that is pretty much what I mean.

Comment: "Verfolgen" is the most likely word. Depending on exact context, "überwachen" could be an alternative. [Compare](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/asset+tracking.html). A third translation, but likely not in your context, is "aufspüren".

Comment: Nur als Notiz für die Zukunft: In ferner Vergangenheit wurde nahegelegt, Fragen bilingual zu stellen. Heutzutage werden Fragen idR in einer Sprache gestellt und – Sonderfälle ausgenommen – auch in dieser beantwortet. In Einzelfällen führt das zwar zu sprachübergreifenden Dubletten, damit werden wir aber fertig. Damit will ich *nicht* sagen, dass das biliguale Fragen verboten seien; nur dass es nicht notwendig ist, die Frage in die andere Sprache zu übersetzen. P.S: Es gibt eine [tour] der Seite, und mehr über ihre Funktionsweise findest du im [help].

Comment: "Inventarverfolgung" ist an sich ein eingeführtes Wort dafür.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Begriff *verfolgen* wird beispielsweise bei der Versendung von Paketen verwendet, da man dort nachvollziehen möchte, wo auf seinem Weg das Paket sich befindet. Man verfolgt es.

In deinem Kontext ist dies tatsächlich eher nicht der Fall, weil der Weg eines Geräts oder Gegenstandes egal ist. Was interessant ist, ist nur der aktuelle Aufenthaltsort.

Das Wort, das mir da als erstes in den Sinn kommt, ist *aufspüren*, was ich in meinem Kommentar oben erwähnt und (vor deinem Edit) bereits ausgeschlossen hatte.
Andererseits spürt man Geräte nicht auf. Ein Suchhund spürt eine Leiche auf. Aber Geräte?!

Daher würde ich es ganz einfach machen: **finden**.

Der Vollständigkeithalber noch einige Alternativen (Reihenfolge weist keine Priorität auf):

- (Gerät) orten
- (aktuellen Ort) bestimmen
- (aktuellen Ort/Gerät) ausmachen
- (aktuellen Ort/Gerät) lokalisieren
- (aktuellen Ort/Status) ermitteln
- (aktuellen Ort/Status) anzeigen
- (aktuellen Ort/Status) feststellen
- (Status) sichten

Comment: Bäh, wollte eine Antwort mit Kern "Lokalisierungssoftware" schreiben, habe dann aber _lokalisieren_ in Deiner Resteliste entdeckt. Hier, nimm Dein +1, pff.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Den Begriff "Lokalisierungssoftware" verbinde ich in erster Linie mit Übersetzungen. Dann eher irgendwas mit "Inventarverwaltung", wie in einer anderen Antwort vorgeschlagen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde "Asset Tracking Software" mit "Inventur Software" übersetzen.

To track something bedeutet ja etwas im Auge zu behalten oder zu verfolgen.
Kann aber auch mit Überwachen übersetzt werden.

Da es um die Überwachung von Geräten geht, würde ich **nachverfolgen** vorschlagen.

Comment: Hab etwas mehr Kontext gegeben. Das Problem ist dass es um eine Anleitung geht und "Die Verfolgung von Geräten" und "Das im Auge behalten von Geräten" Hört sich nicht besonders richtig/professionel an.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit sowas: Die Software bietet die Möglichkeit den Status/Verbleib der Geräte zu Überwachen/ nach zu verfolgen?

Comment: Es müsste *Inventur-Software* (oder *Inventursoftware*) geschrieben werden.

Answer (score 1):

Bestandsverwaltung or even more formally Inventarverwaltung would be the closest term.

Answer (score 0):

Soweit ich die Frage verstanden habe, geht es nicht darum, die Geräte wiederzufinden um sie zurückzuholen, sondern darum, zu wissen, wo sich die Gerätschaften befinden, und möglicherweise, sie zu buchen oder zu reservieren.

Daher schlage ich *Geräteverwaltungssystem* oder *Materialverwaltungssystem* vor.
oder etwas neudeutscher: *Gerätemanagement*.

Comment: Yes, the former would be a Nachverfolgung.