# How to translate asset (in a track and trace software)

Tags: english-to-german

We have a track and trace software that works together with a device that is attached to assets (could be cars, containers, chassis, rail-waggons, etc.). The task is now to find a general term for those assets in German. It is not the idea to track our device, so "Gerät" will not do. Any ideas?

Please note that I saw [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26444/wie-sagt-man-to-track-an-asset-auf-deutsch-how-would-you-say-to-track-an), but although asking for translation of asset tracking, this was about the tracking part, not the asset.

Comment: What does your dictionary suggest and what do you think?

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/asset or also: http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/asset.html

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Tatsächlich paßt leider *nichts* aus den Wörterbuchlinks - Höchstens vielleicht "Gut", das aber nicht besonders gut [sic].

Comment: @tofro: »Asset« ist aber auch ein äußerst schwammiges Wort. Dagegen ist ja »device« geradezu ein Leuchtturm der Prägnanz. Ich glaube, die beste Übersetzung ist noch immer »Dings« (nicht ganz ernst gemeint).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Eine hochsprachlich akzeptable Form von "Dings" ist "Gegenstand" ;)  - Das ist keine allzuschlechte Übersetzung

Comment: To people voting to close this as "look up in a dictionary": Most German dictionaries fail to come up with a proper translation of the term *asset* in this context.

Comment: If you wish to be very general, and a bit informal, then *Zeug*.

Comment: @tofro: Dennoch ist es hilfreich, wenn der Frager auflistet, was er bereits besucht hat (dann müssen es nicht 20 Leute, die antworten wollen, auch tun) und was er gefunden hat.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist richtig, und der Fragesteller hat dafür auch Schimpfe verdient, aber kein Grund, die  Frage schließen zu wollen.

Comment: Doch. Frage wird geschlossen. Frager heilt die Frage. Frage wird wieder geöffnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky - There is no real 100% translation of *asset* into German. I could imagine the following notations:

- [verfolgtes] Objekt
- [verfolgtes] Wirtschaftsgut, Bestandsgut or, even more general "Gut"
- Gegenstand
- Ziel (but could be mistaken as "destination", while here it has to mean "target being tracked")
- Ausrüstungsgegenstand (only of limited use)
- Artikel
- Posten
- In a very, very loose sense maybe even "Aktivum" (as singular of "Aktiva", which is the proper translation of *assets*)

For generic asset tracking, I would probably tend to "[verfolgtes] Bestandsgut", even if it is a whole lot longer than "asset".

And there is always the simple way out of not translating at all: "Asset" is a German word mentioned in a lot of dictionaries. It is, however, very rarely used for "asset item" in German. In an asset tracking system, I would assume people to know what you are talking about, though...

NB: Sometimes the [MS Language portal](https://www.microsoft.com/language/de-de/Search.aspx?sString=asset&langID=de-de) tends to come up with proper translation of IT relevant language. Unfortunately, there are no real good proposals for *asset*, however.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

> [Mobilien](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mobilien) =  bewegliche Sachen, beweglicher Besitz (im Unterschied
>   zu den Immobilien)

which is moveable property, opposed to

> [Immobilie](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Immobilie)n = unbeweglicher Besitz

Answer (score 1):

Other manufacturer of similar devices describe their assets as

> Fahrzeuge und Objekte

"Objekte" are especially the containers, as they are not vehicles.

Another possible term could be

> Mobile Objekte

as all things you mentioned are mobile.

And a last possible term could be

> Verkehrsobjekte

as all things have something to do with traffic. But this term would be rather strange and artifical.

Answer (score 0):

You wont find a single matching word which is still understable, I'm afraid. The use of "asset" in your business is already very specific and I doubt anyone who hasn't already got knowledge about it would understand more than "doohickey".

I would translate the term *container* into German because we assume it's those huge metal boxes (which you don't mean exclusively) and even add *aller Art*. Then, add the trailers and waggons.

> Transportbehälter aller Art sowie Auflieger und Güterwagen.